# ios7 suddenly navigation bar height change

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

hi i want to solution in ios7's problem.

My classes is

```
AlphaViewController : UIViewController,
BetaViewController : UIViewController
```

when `AlphaViewController` will appear, Alpha's navigation bar hight is `44.0f`.
looks like too. and Supported Orientation is Portrait.

then I use `presentmodalViewController` for `BetaViewController`.
`BetaViewController`'s navigation bar will be hide in `viewWillAppear`.
and Supported Orientation is LandScape.

then I use `popViewController` function. so `AlphaViewController` will be appear again.
I use `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

But suddenly Alpha's navigation bar hight is changed.
It looks like `22.0f`. I don't know reason..

my english is not good.
thanks to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all `presentModalViewController:` is deprecated since ios6 so you may not use it for presenting an view controller.

When you present a **viewController** from an **navigationController** if you want the navigation bar to be present on **AlphaViewController** you dont need to hide or un hide. Since you are presenting the **BetaViewController** navigation bar will not appear and when you dismiss it will be visible again in  **AlphaViewController**.